# org.apache.commons.configuration.INIConfiguration: section name with dot (period)

Tags: java, configuration, ini

I have an ini configuration, which I read with org.apache.commons.configuration.INIConfiguration. This works fine.
But now I have a sectionname with a dot (perod) in my configuration.

```
[fineSection]
fineKey = fineValue

[worry.Section]
worryKey = worryValue
```

Here my code:

```
String content = getMyConfiguration();
INIConfiguration iniConfiguration = new INIConfiguration();
iniConfiguration.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()));
Set<?> sections = iniConfiguration.getSections();
```

I get

```
sections = [fineSection, worry].
```

But I need

```
sections = [fineSection, worry.Section].
```

How can solve this problem, is it possible?

Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score -1):

Use Commons Configuration version 2.2

Comment: Please elaborate by adding a link or some references.